# Can Google App Engine ever support SSL with custom domains (i.e. with Google Apps)?

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google App Engine support SSL for apps hosted as mydomain.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593197/does-google-app-engine-support-ssl-for-apps-hosted-as-mydomain-com)

I know that GAE does not support this yet, but is there any reason it can't be done? If they can add support, I'd assume they're working on that. Have they said anything about this publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine has now launched [SSL for Custom Domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl). You can choose from either SNI or VIP based SSL. Wildcard and multi domain certificates are supported which allow you to use your certificates across multiple applications and domains.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different ways they might choose to handle this, including automatic IP address re-routing and [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).  It has been one of the most requested features for [well over a year](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component), and very recently, they officially put it on their [Product Roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html).  It was also mentioned in their App Engine for Business [announcement](http://code.google.com/appengine/business/).

Comment: Thanks for all the links! The Google Code issue says the priority if this issue is medium though. Of course, it's always hard to set or interpret priority/severity of an issue in a bug tracker.

Answer (score 3):

[SSL for custom domains is supported](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-ssl-for-custom-domains-in.html) for tests since October 2011.

**Update:**
Full description of [SSL for a Custom Domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).

Comment: It's in trusted tester, not "supported for tests"

Answer (score 1):

They can - there is no technical reason why not, especially with newer TLS versions (RFC 4366) which support virtual hosted SSL/TLS. Before this point an SSL session required a dedicated IP per certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately, browser support for SNI isn't widespread enough yet to be a practical solution.

Comment: SNI support isn't ubiquitous yet, but it is coming very close. Pretty much all the major browsers support it now as well as the OpenSSL libraries, really the only thorn left is Windows XP - it limits a number of browsers on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such support at the moment but it's noted in the [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) for upcoming releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can run SSL on your custom domain by using a third-party service.  Here's a HOWTO I wrote up explaining how to do it using CloudFlare:

http://blorn.com/post/20185054195/ssl-for-your-domain-on-google-app-engine

They found an interesting way around the one-cert-per-IP address.  Since they register the certificates, they register each cert with 20+ domains on it.  That way they multiplex 20 different domains on a single IP address.

At any rate, we use it at Voost and we're pretty happy with it.

Comment: Downvotes?  Really?  For an answer that explains exactly how to solve the problem described in the question?  I am astounded.

Comment: Some people downvote answers so their answer is higher in a hope that OP would choose it instead :)